# CallKit for Videocalls

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I searched a lot in Stack Overflow and many blogs but couldn't get the proper solution. I like to use the CallKit in video call application, is it possible ?

I saw that whatsApp also not used the CallKit for its video call application. If it possible means refer any proper solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Callkit for videocalls, as an example, we have our code prepare for it, but we don't use Callkit for two reasons:

- There is no difference on the Callkit screen with voice calls except text, so the user can answer the call as a voice call and put the phone near his ear.
- When you have the iPhone blocked and you answer an incoming videocall (and you didn't read that this was a videocall instead a voice call), iOS don't change to your app, and, therefore, you can't show the image receive.

I hope this answers your question